# Show message and download file after password verified - Razor pages

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

Before download the file, user need to enter the password. So I want to show the message if password is correct and in the same time start the download the file to the user.

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            var getFileUpload = await _context.FileUpload.FirstAsync(c => c.Guid == Guid && c.ExpiredOn.HasValue);

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var message = string.Join(" | ", ModelState.Values
                                .SelectMany(v => v.Errors)
                                .Select(e => e.ErrorMessage));

                return BadRequest(message);
            }

            if (DateTime.Today > getFileUpload.ExpiredOn.Value.AddDays(1))
            {

                Exception = "File already expired. Please ask administrator to share again";

                return Page();
            }

          

            try
            {
                bool verified = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(Password, getFileUpload.PasswordHash);

                if (!verified)
                {
                    Exception = "Password is wrong, please enter correct password";

                    return Page();
                }

                byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(getFileUpload.Path);

                var fileName = getFileUpload.FileName;

                File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);

                Success = true;

                return Page();
            }
            catch
            {
                Exception = "Failed to download the data";

                return Page();
            }


         
        }
```

I can see the message, but file cannot download.

But when I change `return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);`, file able to download but cannot not alert the message.

Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can verify the password with ajax first, and get the file after success. This is the pagemodel code.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        //other code
        if (true)
        {
            return new JsonResult("success");
        }
        else
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

    }
    public IActionResult OnGetFileAsync()
    {
        //get file from header
        StringValues filename;
        Request.Headers.TryGetValue("filename", out filename);

        var stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead("file path");
        string fileExt = Path.GetExtension("1.png");
        var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
        var memi = provider.Mappings[fileExt];
        return File(stream, memi, Path.GetFileName("filename"));
    }
```

Ajax in the page.

```
function verify() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/?handler',
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
            RequestVerificationToken: $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
        },
        success: function (data,status) {
            fetch("/?handler=file", {
                    //Write the filename to be obtained into the http header
                    headers: {
                        'filename': data
                    }
                }).then(res => res.blob().then(blob => {
                    var a = document.createElement('a');
                    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);  
                    var filename = res.headers.get('content-disposition').split(';')[1].split('=')[1]
                    a.href = url;
                    a.download = filename;
                    a.click();
                    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                })); 
             //set successful message
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log('e')
            //set the error message in the page
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: I think this method someone can by pass just simplify enter `/?handler=file` in browser right?

Comment: @AzriZakaria Yes, I give you a more safer way to transfer files. When sending a download request to the backend, pass in the file name through the header.